# Can this be turned into a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to clean this up with a For loop. What would be the most efficient way coding this out?

I'm creating a search form that looks through a database for the specific form criteria. The way I have it coded would only work for the 8 Fields. But it is possible for the search form to have more then 8. For now though, I'd like to be able to map the results and display in a results page.

This is what I tried. This did not work at all and probably make no sense to anyone lol.

```
 var obj =data[0]

$.get("obj", {data: $('select["Fields.DisplayName" + Fields.DataValue]').val()}, 
            function(data){
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    alert(item);
                });
            }
);
```

This works for getting the data and displaying it how I'd like.

```
var obj = data[0];

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 
"<p>"+ obj.Fields[0].DisplayName + ":  " + obj.Fields[0].DataValue + "</p>" +
"<p>" + obj.Fields[1].DisplayName + ":  " + obj.Fields[1].DataValue + "</p>" +  
"<p>"+ obj.Fields[2].DisplayName + ":  " + obj.Fields[2].DataValue + "</p>" +  
"<p>"+ obj.Fields[3].DisplayName + ":  " + obj.Fields[3].DataValue + "</p>" +
"<p>" + obj.Fields[4].DisplayName + ":  " + obj.Fields[4].DataValue + "</p>" +
"<p>" + obj.Fields[5].DisplayName + ":  " + obj.Fields[5].DataValue + "</p>" +  
"<p>"+ obj.Fields[6].DisplayName + ":  " + obj.Fields[6].DataValue + "</p>" +
"<p>" + obj.Fields[7].DisplayName + ":  " + obj.Fields[7].DataValue + "</p>" 
    ;
```

The next problem is if there is more then 1 data object. Currently I have it set to loop through the first object, but when I remove that I get cannot read property of '0' undefined.

Comment: Yes. Have you tried anything yet? If you have, what went wrong (errors, unexpected results, etc.)?

Comment: What would happen if your `Fields` array have more than `8` elements, would you discard all the ones that come after, or do you want all the available on the array?

Comment: I tried the doing a for loop, but my logic was incorrect.

Comment: Yes it is possible for there to be more then 8 fields in the array.

Comment: If you post your best attempt as well as explain what went wrong, your question will be better received. Some of the downvotes may even be reversed. You can click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54370438/edit) link under your question to make changes at any time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Array.map()` and join the results:

```
var fields = data[0].Fields ;

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = fields
  .map(function(field) {
    return '<p>' + field.DisplayName + ': ' + field.DataValue + '</p>';
  })
  .join('\n');
```

Answer (score 5):

Sure.

```
var html = "";
obj.Fields.forEach(({DisplayName, DataValue}) => {
  html += `<p>${DisplayName}: ${DataValue}</p>`;
});
document.getElementById("test").innerHtml = html;
```