# How can I loop through multiple objects in a api array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

With my current code, I'm able to loop through a single object to get the data I need. I'm running into a problem trying to loop through all of the available objects, so that I can get the data from all objects returned from the ajax search.

This is the code I am using to search through a single object.

```
$.ajax({
 url: "",
 type: "get",
 async: true,
 contentType: "application/json",
 success: function(data) {
 console.log(data);


   var fields = data[0].Fields ;


 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = fields
 .map(function(field) {
  return '<p>' + field.DisplayName + ': ' + field.DataValue + '</p>';
  })
 .join('\n');
```

I tried removing the [0] in the var fields = data[0].fields , but I get map is undefined.

When I tried adding a for loop to search through all available objects I'm pretty sure I set it up wrong. I get cannot read property length of undefined...

```
  var fields = data.Fields ;
  for(i = 0; i > fields.length; i++){
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = fields
 .map(function(field) {
  return '<p>' + field.DisplayName + ': ' + field.DataValue + '</p>';
 })
 .join('\n');
 }
```

Here is the console.log(data) output

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {Fields: Array(8), DocImage: {…}}
1: {Fields: Array(8), DocImage: {…}}
2: {Fields: Array(8), DocImage: {…}}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: can you add console.log(data) output?

Comment: Just added it to the end of the question

Comment: Would be helpful if you can add the stringifyed data, atleast for a couple of records.

Comment: You just asked about [how to loop through `Fields`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370438). And now you're asking how to loop through `data`. Maybe you ought to spend some more time on how arrays, objects and for loops works in javascript.

Comment: That right. Thanks for your helpful insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your answer I guess your data is something like:

```
var data = [{Fields: [{DisplayName: 1, DataValue: 1}, {DisplayName: 2, DataValue: 2}], DocImage: '1'},
            {Fields: [{DisplayName: 11, DataValue: 11}, {DisplayName: 22, DataValue: 22}], DocImage: '2'},
            {Fields: [{DisplayName: 31, DataValue: 31}, {DisplayName: 32, DataValue: 32}], DocImage: '3'}] ;
```

If that's true your cycle can be:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data.map(function(field) {
    return field.Fields.map(function(e) {
        return '<p>' + e.DisplayName + ': ' + e.DataValue + '</p>';
    }).join('<br/>');
}).join('<br/>');
```

```js
var data = [{Fields: [{DisplayName: 1, DataValue: 1}, {DisplayName: 2, DataValue: 2}], DocImage: '1'},
{Fields: [{DisplayName: 11, DataValue: 11}, {DisplayName: 22, DataValue: 22}], DocImage: '2'},
{Fields: [{DisplayName: 31, DataValue: 31}, {DisplayName: 32, DataValue: 32}], DocImage: '3'}] ;

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data.map(function(field) {
    return field.Fields.map(function(e) {
        return '<p>' + e.DisplayName + ': ' + e.DataValue + '</p>';
    }).join('<br/>');
}).join('<br/>');
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through the data array not the `Fields` property:

```
  for(i = 0; i > data.length; i++){
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data[i].fields
 .map(function(field) {
  return '<p>' + field.DisplayName + ': ' + field.DataValue + '</p>';
 })
 .join('\n');
 }
```

Comment: I tried that, but I don't get anything to show up . No error msg either

Answer (score 0):

Based on the structure of the data the API is giving you, you could loop within a loop; e.g.:

```js
const data = [
  {Fields: [{DisplayName: 'a', DataValue: 1}]},
  {Fields: [{DisplayName: 'b', DataValue: 2}, {DisplayName: 'c', DataValue: 3}]},
];

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data.map(({Fields}) => (
  Fields.map(({DisplayName, DataValue}) => (
    `<p>${DisplayName}: ${DataValue}</p>`
  )).join('\n')
)).join('\n');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id=test></p>
  </body>
</html>
```